# Fast conditional forward fill in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to efficiently perform a particular operation on each column of a `DataFrame`. In each column, if an entry is followed by some sequence consisting of the same number which is lower than the entry, followed by the entry again, and this sequence is not longer than *k*, then fill in the sequence by the "bracketing" entry.

For example, suppose *k=2*. Then, the following `DataFrame`

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  6  6  6  6  6
1  7  7  5  6  6
2  7  7  5  5  5
3  6  7  5  5  5
4  5  6  6  6  9
5  9  9  9  9  6
```

should be transformed into:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  6  6  6  6  6
1  7  7  5  6  6
2  7  7  5  6  5
3  6  7  5  6  5
4  5  6  6  6  9
5  9  9  9  9  6
```

Notice that only the sequence of 5's in column 3 is filled. In columns 0 and 1 the sequence of 7's is left as is because *7>6*. In column 2, *5<6* but the sequence is of length 3, which is above *k=2*. Column 4 is left unchanged because the sequence of 5's is followed by an entry (9) that is different from the entry preceeding it (6).

**Summary of conditions for filling:**:

1. The sequence consists of the same number, and this number is lower than the entry before the sequence starts.
2. The sequence is of length less than or equal to k.
3. The entry right after the sequence is the same as the entry preceeding the sequence.

I can do it in a loop but it takes awfuly long as my `DataFrame` is large. Can someone suggest an efficent (speed) way of acheiving this?

Comment: So you want to forward fill a portion of  a column if the length of the sequence of repeated numbers in the column is less than k (or is it equal to k?) **and** the repeated numbers are less than the previous row?

Comment: Yes @James, to be precise, the following three conditions must hold:
1) the sequence consists of the same number, and this number is lower than the entry before the sequence starts.
2) the sequence is of length less than or equal to k. 
3) The entry right after the sequence is the same as the entry preceeding the sequence.